# How to use the templates for Kendo UI autocomplete using MVVM observable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvvm, kendo-ui

I'm new to Kendo UI and still learning a lot. My requirement is to create a multi-column auto complete drop down list. I followed the below link using Kendo UI autocomplete text box with templates. 
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/template.html.

However I could not find an example that uses templates with an auto completion using..

> kendo.observable.

I use MVVM observable to binds the data to an input box as below.

```
 <div id="form-container">
    <h2>
        Advisors</h2>
    Select Advisor:
    <div class="autocomplete">
        <input id="div-template" data-role="autocomplete" data-text-field="AdvisorName" data-filter="contains" data-bind="source: advisorsSource, value: selectedAdvisor" />
    </div>
 </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {

    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        advisorsSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            minLength: 2,
            template: '<tr>' +
                    '<td>${ AdvisorCode }</dt><td>${ AdvisorName }</td><td>${ Organisation }</td>' +
                  '</tr>',
            transport: {
                type: "json",
                serverFiltering: true,
                read: "Home/Advisors",
                parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return {
                            models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
                        };
                    }
                    return {
                        prefix: options.filter.filters[0].value
                    }; 
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: { id: "AdvisorCode" }
            }               
        })
    });

    kendo.bind($("#form-container"), viewModel);
})

</script>
```

HomeController has the Action which return Json as below:

```
 public JsonResult Advisors(string prefix)      
 {
       var list = new List<Advisor>()
       {
              new Advisor { AdvisorCode = 002, AdvisorName = "Alex" , Organisation = "Blue Co"},
              new Advisor { AdvisorCode = 003, AdvisorName = "Foo" , Organisation = "Yellow Co"},
              new Advisor { AdvisorCode = 004, AdvisorName = "Smith", Organisation = "Green Co" },
              new Advisor { AdvisorCode = 005, AdvisorName = "David", Organisation = "Yellow Co" },
              new Advisor { AdvisorCode = 006, AdvisorName = "Alex" , Organisation = "Blue Co"},   
        };

        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
```

The auto completion works ok. However it only shows AdvisorName. It seems like my template does not work as expected.

I need to display multi-column (AdvisorCode | AdvisorName | Organisation) in the drop down, and the search should be based on any of these columns ( not just the AdvisorName).

Can anyone please point me to the right direction on how to use the template so I can display multi columns?

Thanks and much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working! Once I moved the template attribute to the input field, it just works. For example please see below.

```
 <input id="advisorautocomp" data-role="autocomplete" 
 data-text-field="Name" data-filter="contains"
        data-bind="source: advisorsSource, value: selectedAdvisor" 
        data-template="template" />
```

Notice: data-template="template"

And the template can be defined as below (an example only).

```
 <script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">      
      <tr><td>${ data.Code }</td><td>${ data.Name }</td></tr>      
 </script>
```

I’m not sure why the javascript template attribute does not work with the kendo.observable, but at this stage the above solution works for me. I posted the same question in [Kendo UI forum](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/autocomplete/how-to-use-the-templates-for-kendo-ui-autocomplete-using-mvvm-observable.aspx), and hopefully they will have a complete answer.